# Are there any other standard ways of bringing network interfaces up at boot, apart from using /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-interface, embedded, yocto

I'm working with a Yocto based embedded system and I want all external network interfaces to default to being disabled at boot.

Normally, I'd assume that they go up at boot because `/etc/network/interfaces` has an `auto <INTERFACE_NAME>` line in it but that doesn't seem to be the case. In fact, there is no mention of the interfaces in question there. I've searched far and wide for the culprit responsible for turning those interfaces off but I'm running out of ideas.

Are there any other standard tools which could be bringing network interfaces up at boot?

Comment: If your installation has systemd, possibly disabling networkmanager will help you `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service`

Comment: I still want to use NetworkManager to manage networks, I just want them to default to disabled. This is because I need my system to have only one network interface enabled at the time, and if they go up by default, both of them might be up before I get to enable/disable them manually.

Comment: Do you have busybox `udhcpd` configured? I guess it brings up your interfaces automatically by default.

Comment: Yeah I've got `udhcpd` running in the system. Is it really configured to bring up interfaces by itself? Gahhh that's annoying.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, disregard the above. udhcpd is not running.

Comment: How about a `udev` rule?